# Can't Observe LiveData from ViewModel in Fragment

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, mutablelivedata

I have a `RecyclerView` in my `ViewPager`'s one of the `Fragment`. This `RecyclerView` show's data that are fetched from Server. It normally works, but I couldn't be able to implement the same feature using `ViewModel` and `LiveData`, because the `livedata.observe` method is not getting called when the `livedata` is being changed from the `ViewModel`.

Here's the Source Code of my **MonthlyOrderViewModel.java** class

```
public class MonthlyOrderViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private Retrofit retrofit;
private RetrofitServices retrofitServices;
private MutableLiveData<MonthlyOrderHistory> monthlyOrderHistoryMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

public MonthlyOrderViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    retrofit = RetrofitFactory.getRetrofit();
    retrofitServices = retrofit.create(RetrofitServices.class);
}

public MutableLiveData<MonthlyOrderHistory> getMonthlyOrderHistoryMutableLiveData() {
    return monthlyOrderHistoryMutableLiveData;
}
public void fetchMonthlyOrders() {
    Call<MonthlyOrderHistory> call = retrofitServices.getAllMonthlyOrderHistory(IpharmaApplication.getInstance().getLoggedInUser().getId());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<MonthlyOrderHistory>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MonthlyOrderHistory> call, Response<MonthlyOrderHistory> response) {

            MonthlyOrderHistory monthlyOrderHistory = response.body();
            if(monthlyOrderHistory.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {

                List<UserOrder> userOrders = monthlyOrderHistory.getOrders().getUserOrder();
                if(userOrders != null && userOrders.size() != 0) {
                    DefaultScheduler.INSTANCE.execute(() -> {
                        monthlyOrderHistoryMutableLiveData.postValue(monthlyOrderHistory);
                        return Unit.INSTANCE;
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MonthlyOrderHistory> call, Throwable t) {

            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}

}
```

`DefaultScheduler` is a `Scheduler` that by default handles operations in the `AsyncScheduler`.
Here's the Source Code of my **Scheduler.kt** class

```
interface Scheduler {

    fun execute(task: () -> Unit)

    fun postToMainThread(task: () -> Unit)

    fun postDelayedToMainThread(delay: Long, task: () -> Unit)
}

//A shim [Scheduler] that by default handles operations in the [AsyncScheduler].
object DefaultScheduler : Scheduler {

    private var delegate: Scheduler = AsyncScheduler

    //Sets the new delegate scheduler, null to revert to the default async one.
    fun setDelegate(newDelegate: Scheduler?) {
        delegate = newDelegate ?: AsyncScheduler
    }

    override fun execute(task: () -> Unit) {
        delegate.execute(task)
    }

    override fun postToMainThread(task: () -> Unit) {
        delegate.postToMainThread(task)
    }

    override fun postDelayedToMainThread(delay: Long, task: () -> Unit) {
        delegate.postDelayedToMainThread(delay, task)
    }
}

//Runs tasks in a [ExecutorService] with a fixed thread of pools
internal object AsyncScheduler : Scheduler {

    private val executorService: ExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS)

    override fun execute(task: () -> Unit) {
        executorService.execute(task)
    }

    override fun postToMainThread(task: () -> Unit) {
        if (isMainThread()) {
            task()
        } else {
            val mainThreadHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
            mainThreadHandler.post(task)
        }
    }

    private fun isMainThread(): Boolean {
        return Looper.getMainLooper().thread === Thread.currentThread()
    }

    override fun postDelayedToMainThread(delay: Long, task: () -> Unit) {
        val mainThreadHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
        mainThreadHandler.postDelayed(task, delay)
    }
}

//Runs tasks synchronously.
object SyncScheduler : Scheduler {
    private val postDelayedTasks = mutableListOf<() -> Unit>()

    override fun execute(task: () -> Unit) {
        task()
    }
    override fun postToMainThread(task: () -> Unit) {
        task()
    }
    override fun postDelayedToMainThread(delay: Long, task: () -> Unit) {
        postDelayedTasks.add(task)
    }
    fun runAllScheduledPostDelayedTasks() {
        val tasks = postDelayedTasks.toList()
        clearScheduledPostdelayedTasks()
        for (task in tasks) {
            task()
        }
    }
    fun clearScheduledPostdelayedTasks() {
        postDelayedTasks.clear()
    }
}
```

And finally, I'm trying to observe the changes from my fragment's `onCreateView` method using this:

```
MonthlyOrderViewModel monthlyOrderViewModel = new MonthlyOrderViewModel(getActivity().getApplication());

monthlyOrderViewModel.getMonthlyOrderHistoryMutableLiveData().observe(this, monthlyOrderHistory -> {

    monthlyOrderRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.monthlyOrderRecyclerView);

    monthlyOrderRecyclerViewAdapter = new OrderHistoryRecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), monthlyOrderHistory.getOrders().getUserOrder());

    monthlyOrderRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    monthlyOrderRecyclerView.setAdapter(monthlyOrderRecyclerViewAdapter);       

    monthlyOrderRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

});
```

I tried to debug it and found that the retrofit had no problem fetching data. But the `observe` method is never getting called when I try to use them in my fragment.

Please suggest me how to solve this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you set the LiveCycleOwner for viewmodel in fragment?

Comment: Yes I, tried. I replaced `monthlyOrderViewModel.getMonthlyOrderHistoryMutableLiveData().observe(this, monthlyOrderHistory -> {`

with  `monthlyOrderViewModel.getMonthlyOrderHistoryMutableLiveData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), monthlyOrderHistory -> {`

but the result was same

Comment: So where are you calling `fetchMonthlyOrders()` to trigger loading data into your `LiveData`? It isn't called anywhere in the code you've provided.

Comment: Yes, I'm calling it at the beginning of my activity using this 
ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MonthlyOrderViewModel.class).fetchMonthlyOrders();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't instantiate your `ViewModel` using `new`. You have to do this instead:

```
MonthlyOrderViewModel monthlyOrderViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MonthlyOrderViewModel.class);
```

If you are sure that the `postValue` is being executed in your ViewModel, then I think that this change should make it work. One more thing: you shouldn't be doing all that every time the observed LiveData notifies you of a change. I would move the next lines before the `observe()`

```
monthlyOrderRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.monthlyOrderRecyclerView);

monthlyOrderRecyclerViewAdapter = new OrderHistoryRecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), monthlyOrderHistory.getOrders().getUserOrder());

monthlyOrderRecyclerView.setAdapter(monthlyOrderRecyclerViewAdapter);       

monthlyOrderRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```

### Update

As Fahim confirmed in the comments, the problem was that multiple instances of the same`ViewModel` were being created. If you need to share the same instance of a `ViewModel`, make sure to pass a reference of the Fragment/Activity that's the "owner" of that ViewModel. For example, if `MyActivity` has a `MainActivityViewModel` and it contains a child Fragment named `MyFragment`, then if that Fragment wants to get a reference to its parent's ViewModel it will have to do it in the following way:

```java
MainActivityViewModel mainActivityVM = ViewModelProviders
                                            .of(getActivity())
                                            .get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
```

Comment: As per your instruction, I tried `ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MonthlyOrderViewModel.class).getMonthlyOrderHistoryMutableLiveData().observe` , but no change. The program is not entering inside Observe. Also, the rest of the program inside the observe is just to show what I'm trying to achieve in minimal code. I would change their position accordingly If the program enters inside observe.

Comment: @FahimAlMahmudAshik are you a 100% sure that this line `monthlyOrderHistoryMutableLiveData.postValue(monthlyOrderHistory);` in your `ViewModel` is being executed?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I put a breakpoint and double checked just now, it executes.

Comment: @FahimAlMahmudAshik  ok I see... Are you observing the ViewModel from a Fragment or an Activity? If the Activity that holds the fragment is the one making the call to fetch, and you are sharing the ViewModel between the fragment and the activity, then try getting your viewmodel in the Fragment using `MonthlyOrderViewModel monthlyOrderViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(MonthlyOrderViewModel.class);` instead. If not, you will end up with two different instances of ViewModel

Comment: Sorry for being late @dglozano. Actually that was the problem, I was recreating new instance of my viewmodel every time. Please edit your answer and add this information so that if anyone else face this issue, they can get a clear answer from the one that you've posted. I'm accepting your answer. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: @FahimAlMahmudAshik happy to hear that it worked!!! I've just edited the answer :)

Comment: Thanks fam, this saved me from literally a whole two days of work, my data was showing in the logs but not in my observer, but after reading this and changing from my fragments owning the viewmodel to using the activity's instance, my data is all here. Thanks a ton